# awk command is not showing expected output

Tags: awk

I am not able to get desired output with below awk command.

```
$ cat /usr/data/doc
8675|Linux|UserA
8975|Linux|UserB
8975|Linux|UserC
8898|Windows|UserD

$ cat go
#!/bin/bash
exec awk -v arg=${1:?} '$1==arg' "${@:2}" /usr/data/doc

$ go 8975
```

Expected output:

```
8975|Linux|UserB
8975|Linux|UserC
```

But with above script it is not providing expected output, it is showing blank.

Comment: `$1` is not equal to `8975` so why do you think the line should be printed?

Comment: $1 is used for first field and parse output based on first field only. Script is saved in a filename go in bin, i am using 'go' and parsing output in first field.

Comment: replace `$1==arg` with `{print $1}` and see what you get...

Comment: Now it is printing all data in first field, expectation is to parse output.

Comment: perhaps you need to define the field separator FS ?

Comment: Hi JHNC, could you please share command.Thanks

Comment: Try with `awk -F'|' ...`. What is this `"${@:2}"` supposed to do? And why do you `exec awk ...` instead of just `awk`?

Comment: please refer below link, this command used to work fine when there is space in each field but now there is no space.   https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/736063/grep-awk-not-returning-expected-result?noredirect=1

Comment: @anukalps ... That's why you need `-F'|'`. Your fields are not space-separated (the `awk` default) so you must tell `awk` that the input field separator is a pipe.

Answer (score 1):

This

```
8675|Linux|UserA
8975|Linux|UserB
8975|Linux|UserC
8898|Windows|UserD
```

is pipe-separated file, GNU `AWK` default behavior is to assume field separator is one-or-more white-space characters. You need to inform GNU `AWK` that it is dealing with pipe-separated file, which can be done by setting `FS` in `BEGIN`, that is

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="|"}$1==8975' /usr/data/doc
```

or if you have `8975` stored as shell variable, say arg

```
arg="8975"
awk -v arg="$arg" 'BEGIN{FS="|"}$1==arg' /usr/data/doc
```

> this command used to work fine when there is space in each field but
> now there is no space

Further investigation is required, can you now assume pipe will always be used as separating character or it might be pipe or space?

If you want to know more about `FS` then read [8 Powerful Awk Built-in Variables – FS, OFS, RS, ORS, NR, NF, FILENAME, FNR](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/01/8-powerful-awk-built-in-variables-fs-ofs-rs-ors-nr-nf-filename-fnr/)

*(tested in GNU Awk 5.1.0)*

Comment: Hi Daweo, there will be always pipe and there could be any number in first field.

Comment: could you please share command, i tried below command but it is still showing no data.                 exec awk -v arg=${1:?} 'BEGIN{FS="|"}$1==arg' /usr/data/doc                                                                        $ go 8975                                                                                                                               $